# Software environments (development, testing, staging, production)

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

In software engineering, there are often multiple "environments" the codebase exists in:

- development
- testing or qa
- staging
- production

What is the Spanish term used for "environment," and how are each of these environments translated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Spanish word for "environment", in this context, is "entorno". So, we can talk about:

- Entorno de desarrollo ("development")
- Entorno de pruebas ("testing")
- Entorno de producción ("production")

**Update**: As for "staging", I have seen the English word itself being used as a loanword, as in "entorno de staging". But, as others have pointed out (thanks, Javi and Ricardo), "entorno de pre-producción" is often used, as well.

Comment: In the companies I've worked in Spain we've used the term "entorno de pre-producción" for staging.

Comment: I've heard "entorno de pre-producción" too.

Comment: I've heard and used "entorno de transición" for "staging environment".

Comment: He conocido el término *staging* como **puesta en línea** para describir el paso de información almacenada en una cinta a un disco para su proceso.