# Traducción correcta de "stage" y "staging" en el contexto de GIT

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Tengo que hacer documentación en español del software GitKraken para Git y la plataforma GitLab y tengo diferentes problemas al traducir ciertos conceptos.

GitKraken utiliza el término "**Staging**", para referirse al proceso para preparar archivos para luego hacer "commit" a estos.

Mi duda es si será necesario traducir el término y usarlo traducido a través de toda la documentación, o si lo dejo así tal cual.

Si lo tradujera ¿sería algo como "**Preparación**" o "**Puesta en escena**"?

Por ejemplo en la siguiente frase de la documentación oficial de GitKraken:

> "Select the files you wish to stage (..) To stage all your files, use
>   the keyboard shortcut..."

Lo cual traducido quedaría algo como:

> "Selecciona los archivos que quieras preparar (...) Para preparar
>   todos sus archivos, use el atajo de teclado..."

O quizás solo sea necesario definir el concepto y después usarlo en inglés, quedando así:

> "Selecciona los archivos que quieras *hacer stage* (...) Para *hacer
>   stage* a todos sus archivos, usa el atajo de teclado..."

pero no suena muy bien...

Además, Gitkraken utiliza el concepto "**Staging area**" para referirse al área de la interfaz donde quedan listados esos archivos preparados, y tampoco sé como definir bien ese concepto.

Por último, GitLab utiliza el concepto "**Staging environment**" como uno de los entornos de desarrollo de las diferentes etapas del flujo de desarrollo de software, pero [en esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1494/8394) se dijo que en español se usaba como "entorno de pre-producción", pero GitLab utiliza los entornos "staging" y "pre-production" de forma separada, siendo "staging" una etapa anterior a "pre-production", por lo que no creo que sea una traducción correcta.

Saludos y espero se entienda.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Gran primera pregunta: interesante, bien formateada y planteada. Espero poder seguir viendo muchas de esta excelentes aportaciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: Muchas gracias :) espero ser un aporte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La versión en español de la documentación de GIT (En el libro electrónico [Fundamentos de GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Empezando-Fundamentos-de-Git)) favorece *staged* como **preparado**.

> Git tiene tres estados principales en los que se pueden encontrar tus archivos: confirmado (committed), modificado (modified), y **preparado (staged)**.

y describe *staging area* como el **área de preparación**.

> [...] las tres secciones principales de un proyecto de Git: el directorio de Git (Git directory), el directorio de trabajo (working directory), y **el área de preparación (staging area)**.

Comment: Muchas gracias, siempre leí toda la documentación en inglés.

Comment: Voto por ello, pero también me parece que falta algo. Cuando haces un `git stage` lo que haces es _separar_ el código para seguir trabajando con él después.

Comment: @fedorqui Según el libro electrónico [Fundamentos de GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Empezando-Fundamentos-de-Git), en el último parrafo, dice que el código o los archivos que están en el area de preparación (*staging area*), se encuentran **preparados** (*staged*). Por lo que al hacer `git stage` estás haciendo eso según [la definición del comando](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stage).

Comment: @FrancoVP ya veo, qué curioso. A base de usar `git` fui creando mis imágenes mentales sobre cómo funciona. Y, en ellas, siempre vi `git stash -u` como una manera de _apartar_ o _separar_ algo momentáneamente de mi vista para luego recuperarlo con `git stash pop`. Vaya, que el problema aquí estriba en cómo lo veo yo, que no encaja con la terminología :)

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo `git stage` con `git stash`, ojo.
Claro, `git stash` es para hacer como "borradores" de tu directorio de trabajo.

Answer (score 5):

La traducción con **preparación** es correcta en lo que se refiere al sentido en el original.

Alternativas podrían ser las familias de los verbos `organizar` y `ordenar`.

Comment: Creo que me quedaré con **preparación**, gracias.

Answer (score 5):

La palabra inglesa *stage* equivale a la española *concentración* en el ámbito deportivo. Hoy día se usa bastante como extranjerismo en España. Por ejemplo, en [esta noticia reciente](http://www.diarideterrassa.es/deportes/2017/05/31/seleccion-espanola-iniciara-hoy-nueva-concentracion-terrassa/58087.html), leemos el siguiente titular:

> La selección española iniciará hoy una nueva concentración en Terrassa

Y el artículo empieza así:

> Fred Soyez ha convocado a 27 jugadores (doce egarenses) para realizar un stage en Terrassa entre hoy y el domingo 11 de junio.

Como ves, la idea es similar a la de GitKraken: reunir los jugadores (o los ficheros) en un lugar con un fin concreto. Aunque, como dice @Diego en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21459/1768), la palabra *preparación* ya se ha utilizado en algún texto técnico, me parece demasiado genérica y no da toda la información que sí incluyen el original *stage* y la alternativa que propongo y que [también propone la Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/stage-traducible-por-concentracion-652/), aunque siempre, como digo, en el ámbito deportivo.

Comment: Muy buena acotación, pero en el contexto del sistema Git lo que haces al hacer "stage" a un archivo es prepararlo o dejarlo listo para hacer un commit (un cambio) con él, por lo que decir "concentrar un archivo" no creo que sea lo correcto.

Comment: @FrancoVP No se concentra un archivo: se concentran todos los que van a entrar en el cambio. Es decir: estoy hablando de la primera acepción del DRAE (*Reunir en un centro o punto lo que estaba separado*). Tienes todos los archivos de tu proyecto, reúnes (concentras) los que van a formar parte del cambio y luego lo subes.

Answer (score 3):

No estoy familiarizado con el concepto, pero te puedo sugerir que mantengas la analogía con el teatro que tiene la palabra inglesa "stage" usando éstas:

> **[montaje](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pis37U6)**
>
> **1**. m. Acción y efecto de montar (‖ armar las piezas de un aparato o máquina).
>
> **2**. m. Combinación de las diversas partes de un todo.
>
> **4**. m. Acción y efecto de montar una obra teatral.
>
> **[montar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PjOk949)**
>
> Del fr. *monter*, y este der. del lat. *mons, montis* 'monte'.
>
> **9**. tr. Armar, poner en su lugar las piezas de cualquier aparato o máquina. U. t. en sent. fig.
>
> **11**. tr. Poner en una casa todo lo necesario para habitarla o, en un negocio, lo necesario para que empiece a funcionar.
>
> **12**. tr. En el teatro, disponer lo necesario para la representación de una obra.

Comment: La segunda definición de montaje calza perfecto con la acción de hacer un *stage* a los archivos en el contexto de Git, ya que básicamente estás preparando uno o varios archivos (o trozos de estos) en un *staging area* para hacer un cambio (un *commit*). No sé si se entiende. Entonces, básicamente estás **montando** un commit en tu *staging area* con esos archivos. Me gusta.