# How do you say "unknown environment" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

I hope this is the right place to post this sort of question.

I have a follow up question to [this post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/software-environments-development-testing-staging-production). For a proof-of-concept app (before we hire a full-time translator) I need to translate the different labels for various software environments into Spanish. With my limited understanding of the language, I know that:

- local environment = entorno local (I think?)
- development environment = entorno de desarrollo
- testing environment = entorno de pruebas
- staging environment = entorno de pre-producción
- demo environment = entorno de demostración
- prod environment = entorno de producción

But how would you specify that the current environment is unknown? In English, I'm using the phrase "unknown environment". In Spanish, would that be "entorno desconocido", or is there a better translation?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, "entorno desconocido" (also "ambiente desconocido") works perfectly.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Want to write your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Gustavson "ambiente" is not the usual translation applied to a software development context.

Comment: @RubioRic It depends on the country.

Comment: @Gustavson Tienes razón

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both "entorno desconocido" and "ambiente desconocido" would be correct translation equivalents for "unknown environment".

Comment: Based on @RubioRic's comment, I'm gunna go with "entorno desconocido". Thanks!

Comment: @MathewAlden Both are used. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_de_prueba: Ambiente de prueba/configuración: Contiene información acerca de la configuración del hardware o software en el cual se ejecutará el caso de prueba.

Answer (score 1):

the translation of "unknown environment" into Spanish would be "entorno desconocido"